# Generate a single key from 2 strings in the both order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to generate a hash from 2 different other ones.
I need this to generate a key from 2 users id.
I would like to be able to crypt the both id like this: `crypt(<USER 1>, <USER 2>) === crypt(<USER 2>, <USER 1>)`.

In another word, whatever the order i crypt the both users ids, i would like the generated key to be the same every time.
I do not need to uncrypt the key, just find the same key from the 2 original users id.

I am not very skilled in crypto, is there a module doing this job ?

Comment: Why not sort the inputs alphabetically and then hash?

Comment: @FelixKling yes this is what i am thinking to do if there is no other choice. Thanks.